# Function Scoped JavaScript Variables ACCESS on a 'NON Strict Mode '

Tags: javascript, function, scope, strict-mode

```js
function scoped() {
  var a = 150;
  let b = 300;
  const c = 500;
}

a = 300; // Why is it possible to access a function scoped variable?
b = 600; // Same as above
c = 1000; // Same as above and also why I can change value of constant?

console.log(a); // Return: 300 - Why it works?
console.log(b); // Return: 600 - Why it works?
console.log(c); // Return: 1000 - Why it works?
```

#### MY QUESTIONS:

1. Why it is possible (in a non strict mode) to access function scoped variables? Should this NOT be allowed?
2. Why I can even change a value of a constant?
3. How does scope or hoisting work behind the scene in this specific case?

Comment: Dupe of /questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript , local variables in a function are different bindings from global variables

Comment: In this program a, b, and c aren't defined before you assign to them in the global scope. If you try to console.log(a) before `a = 300`, you get an error because it's undefined.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I got that. According to scope chain it should only be possible to access outer scoped variables. In my case though I'm doing the opposite, I'm trying to access inner scoped variables (from global to function scope). This is what I don't really understand. And also why I can even change a constant value?

Comment: But `c` isn't constant in the global scope. `c` is also not defined until `c = 1000`. The `const c` in the function is simply not accessible from outside it. In fact, none of the three are.

Answer (score 0):

the "var" keyword creates global scope variables not block scope variables in JS. means that  "a" inside the function, it is same "a" outside it or (in the global scope).

the "const,let" keywords create a "block scope" variables, which means the b,c inside the function is not the same b,c outside it. there are two of b,c variables 1- inside the function 2- in the global scope (outside of the function).

sorry for my English, I hope that clear to you.

Comment: you are right with a, it is an execution context scope. but with const, let  as I said. :)

Comment: Thanks both of you. It all make sense now     

Comment: Can't vote you up as apparently I haven't any reputation on Stackoverflow yet guys :(

Comment: @FrankMontana Accepting is fine, since you're the OP.